# CakePHP + NGINX + Memcache

Tags: cakephp, nginx, memcached

I am trying to use Memcache on NGINX for CakePHP (2.4.7) but when I update the core.php & bootstrap.php to do this I am then thrown the following exception:

**Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'CacheException' with message 'Cache engine _cake_core_ is not properly configured**

I have tried to search if any other configuration is required but can't see anything. Any help would be appreciated

Thanks,

Comment: How you configured Cache? Update you question with Cache configuration..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you need be sure that your Memcached configured and working properly.
Check memcached port (11211 if default settings) / process etc... for example memcached -u www-data -vv.
Then if you using memcached default configurations you should change core.php configurations like following:
Uncomment section about memcached. After it it's should looks like this:

```
Cache::config('default', array(
'engine' => 'Memcache', //[required]
'duration' => 1800, //[optional]
'probability' => 100, //[optional]
'prefix' => Inflector::slug(APP_DIR) . '_',
'servers' => array(
    '127.0.0.1:11211'),
'persistent' => true,
'compress' => false));
```

Now change $engine = 'File'; to $engine = 'Memcache';

Use caching for example in controller you need write data with key => value, then access that data with key. Example:

```
Cache::write($key, $value);
Cache::read($key);
```

That's all.
Hope it's help you.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I had updated the core.php & bootstrap.php files as mentioned above but will test that memcached is working itself and report back

Thanks again

Comment: You don't need change anything in bootstrap when already changed in core.